# Creating quick GUI front ends

Tags: user-interface, frontend

I wanted to have a GUI front-end for a script that accepts numerous command-line options, most of them are UNIX paths. So I thought rather than typing them in (even with auto-completion) every time, I'd create a GUI front end which contains text boxes with buttons beside them, which when clicked will invoke the file browser dialogue. Later, I thought I'd extend this to other scripts which would sure require a different set of GUI elements. This made me think if there's any existing app that would let me create a GUI dialog, after parsing some kind of description of the items that I want that window should contain.

I know of programs like Zenity, but I think it's doesn't give me what I want. For example, if I were to use it for the first script, it'll end up flashing sequence of windows in succession rather than getting everything done from a single window.

So, basically I'm looking at some corss-platform program that lets me create a window from a text description, probably XML or the like. Please suggest.

Thanks
Jeenu

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that I was looking for a cross-platform solution (I just edited my post)

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla's XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL) is a cross platform application framework -  .  You could write an app as a Firefox plugin or a standalone XUL application.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had almost forgotten XUL. But I don't think it's a good idea to add dependency on a browser, for a completely unrelated script. I mean it's possible that Firefox isn't installed at all. Let me see. Thanks again.

Comment: May still be too heavyweight, but there's also XULRunner which you can use to eliminate the dependency on a browser and have a self contained package.

Answer (score 0):

mono and [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) could work for this. Or even something super simple like [shoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoes_(GUI_toolkit)).